# Packet sniffing SMTP connection

Tags: windows, smtp, email-server, packet-sniffer

I have a program on Windows that sends email via a remote SMTP server, and it is failing with an ambiguous "cannot connect" error message with no log or other information as to why it is failing. I have tested the SMTP server and confirmed it is working with the same credentials.

The program uses plaintext login to the server, as it doesn't support SSL/TLS, so the SMTP connection should be transmitted in the clear. Is there an easy way to use a packet sniffer to monitor the attempted connection, to see exactly what is being sent (in an effort to discover why the connection is failing)?

Answer (score 6):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Install that sucker, fire it up, start a capture, and Bob's yer uncle.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is. Install a packet capture program on the client (Wireshark, Microsoft Network Monitor, etc.) and start a capture, then start your program and invoke the email function, then look at the capture. You can filter the capture by protocol (SMTP) or by source/destination ip address to filter all of the "noise" out of the capture to allow you to focus on only the conversation that you're interested in.